# Archivo htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Buenos dias, necesito que las URL que van escritas con # el servidor automáticamente las escriba con %23 que es de la única manera que funciona, algún ejemplo con el archivo htacces ? porfavor.

Comment: Las urls no van escritas con # al servidor. El # se lo queda el cliente.

Comment: En este caso si van escritas por que estoy indexando un archivo de extension cualquier y el archivo va nombrado con un # en vez de un _ ejemplo: mi#archivo#cualquiera.mp3 , lo que necesito es que el htacces reescriba ese # ya sea por un _ o por %23

Comment: Si desde tu servidor necesitas generar una url con #, en cambio, usando funciones como `urlencode` (depende de la tecnologia y framework que uses) te van a poner el # como %23 automaticamente. Pero si lo que pretendes es que de alguna manera algun punto intermedio en tu servidor transforme # en %23, entonces olvidate: el # nunca se envia en la peticion al servidor.

Comment: Bien, tengo un buscador de archivos en php, el funciona bien, pero los archivos que se almacenarán para que sean buscados tiene desafortunadamente el en su nombre el # por ende el servidor no va poder abrir el archivo, asi que busco la manera de colocarlo que en vez # sea _ o %23

Comment: Si clickeas algo como http://www.example.org/mi#archivo#cualquiera.mp3 el servidor recibira peticion a http://www.example.org/mi. Si clickeas algo como http://www.example.org/descargar.php?archivo=mi#archivo#cualquiera.mp3 el servidor recibira http://www.example.org/descargar.php?archivo=mi. Sino decime que browser estas usando porque es re loco eso, fuera de estandar.

Comment: Pienso que deberias replantear la arquitectura de tu solucion. # es un caracter muy desafortunado y basta con que clickees en chrome lo que te acabo de pasar para que lo veas. Si lo que buscas es ajax, y lo haces con `jQuey.get`, entonces no vas a tener problema porque te hace los %23 automaticamente.

Comment: Estoy usando google chrome la última versión, esto es re jodido, adjunto un screen de pantalla para que le entiendan mejor. http://www.mediafire.com/view/p90tuw5fo9pxrk9/1.png

Comment: Te estoy escribiendo la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, es muy oscuro lo que estas poniendo con los caracteres #. En lo personal los desaconsejo totalmente (lo mejor seria usar caracteres que sean seguros para una url y no tener que escapar nada, aunque los frameworks te bancan).

Si queres enviar esa URL al servidor (ej. cliquear un link para descargar un archivo) te la hago corta:

No importa como te lo plantees, una peticion a una url como http://www.example.org/mi#archivo#cualquiera.mp3 **no va a enviar JAMAS** el hash ni lo que siga.

Si queres en realidad escupir esa URL desde el servidor al cliente, recomiendo que uses las funciones normalmente llamadas *url encode*. Estas te van a escapar caracteres *desafortunados* como ese en tu esperado %23.

En suma: **no hay nada que puedas hacer en tu .htaccess** sino que te corresponde en el software.

Veamoslo en concreto:

1. Entiendo que tu browser accede a la "url" /buscador/#Grabaciones%2FTigo. Aprendete esto antes de que te hagas quilombo: Al servidor solo le estas mandando GET /buscador/. El servidor te esta respondiendo algun codigo HTML con JS (que hace la parte interactiva del browser). El JS devuelto en algun momento esta procesando de manera propia el valor de `location.hash`, que contiene "Grabaciones/Tigo". Esa manera propia puede ser, ponele, una llamada Ajax.
2. El servidor te esta devolviendo resultados, y uno de ellos parece ser una url con /camino/a/archivo/daniel#garces.mp3. Cuando intentes acceder a el (descargandolo) te vas a dar cuenta que tu servidor no funciona porque intenta acceder a /camino/a/archivo/daniel. No se como estas obteniendo estos datos pero al momento de incrustar ese valor en el html del cliente, deberias asegurarte de escaparlo primero (javascript tiene decodeURIComponent() mientras que php creo que tiene urldecode, pero eso depende de si ese dato lo devolves dentro de un fragmento html por ajax, o dentro de un fragmento js o json por ajax).
3. En ningun punto metimos al .htaccess porque de antemano NUNCA va a recibir dicho caracter #.

Comment: Vaya" luis se nota que tienes experiencia en este tema, la verdad es que soy muy novato este script lo encontré en github y es bastante sencillo, se acomoda a lo que necesito, el inconveniente es que todos los archivos que se guardan estan escritos con el # reemplazandolo por un espacio, adjunto el codigo fuente haber si pueden detectar donde se encuentra el problema, claro está solo si lo pueden hacer... http://www.mediafire.com/download/1lk2c8blhzsssw8/buscador.rar son nada mas el archivo scan.php que hace la busqueda a traves de un js que esta en la carpeta assets/js

Comment: Naaah eso es un esfuerzo enorme y estoy en la oficina. Deberias responsabilizarte bien de aprender las cosas que estas usando, y por el amor de Dios NUNCA USES PHP SIN ALGUN FRAMEWORK QUE TE AGUANTE (menos aun si no comprendes las cosas que le estas agregando, como ese buscador). Es peligrosisimo y no esperes que no te lo hackeen. Mi consejo: Laravel o Yii. Cuesta pero es mejor creeme.

Comment: Bueno de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Tal vez, pero no del todo. Es muy propenso a errores y agujeros de seguridad hacer cualquier cosa web (con cualquier lenguaje, pero hago enfasis en particular en PHP porque es el caso mas comun) sin un soporte intrinseco para evitar inyecciones. Ademas, es muy demorado no tener un MVC y hacer una de esas cosas de gran alcance que Daniel hace. Eso sin mencionar la memoria que te puede comer un buscador cuando eso no escale y necesiten un cache... bueno todo un tema. Si tenes experiencia en hacer apps de gran escala deberias entenderme perfectamente. No son cosas tan imaginarias xD.

Comment: **No coja el carro si no es un ferrari antes de aprender a conducir** Uno de los handicaps mas grandes que se ven por aqui, es empezar a programar desde el framework hacia abajo. El resultado, preguntas que denotan una falta total de conocimiento del lenguaje, del sistema, de todo. Primero apredner a programar, aprender un poco de sistemas (donde va mi programa, que servidor web usa, que tecnologia db, etc..) y luego pasen a los frameworks. Tam,bien quizas, alguno pordira empezar por programar "hola mundo" y despues saltar a un crawler"

Comment: Es verdad que el MVC mola mucho, ya sea Laravel, Django o Angular, pero eso de que el PHP a pelo falle tanto.... nose de donde, ya que llevo usando PHP años y no he tenido tantos problemas como comentas. Todo depende de lo estructurado y depurado que seas en tu código.

Comment: No es intrinsecamente falloso, pero arrastra una cultura muy fea de esto: `mysql_query("select * from mytable where id = $id", $myhandler)`. Si recien aprendes PHP lo normal es que te topes con algo asi y lo repitas. Si empezas PHP usando Laravel (como yo empece Python usando Django y no tuve ningun problema a pesar de mi inexperiencia en python) esas cosas las tenes resueltas desde antes.

Comment: Bueno finalmente he logrado obtener una solución y es bastente acertiva todo lo que este en el directorio lo renombre, con la funcion rename luego coloque la función str replace y para que no consumiera recursos del servidor le coloque un condicional si el archivo no tiene el # pues no haga nada, si lo tiene, renombrelo es todo y ha funcionado.